# c# Windows Form How Insert Data in my server pc "using phpmyadmin"?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
Error Show: INSERT command denied to user 'root'@'202.5.56.75' for table 'life'
```

I need insert data in my business database where table life available.

Bellow code I am write but not going insert. 
Already added MySQL.dll.

```cs
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

string constring="datasource=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query = "insert into business.life (Email_id,First_Name) values('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox1.Text + "') ;";
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
MySqlDataReader myReader;

try
{
    conDataBase.Open();
    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    while (myReader.Read())
    {

    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

If anyone know any good solution Please help me. I am new in the programming position.

Comment: It's probably a really bad idea to give us access to your site. I hope nobody in the SO community will attempt to exploit you, but I think it would be wise to remove this question and restate it without the link to your PHP administration site.

Comment: As an aside - even without leaking your own administration site details, your chosen username and password combo is probably not wise.

Answer (score 0):

This error isn't coming from problematic code, but database permissions rather. You need to grant insert privileges for your root user.

Comment: Thanks for your help it's totally was database permission issue. Really Thanks.